# PHP Insert query - dont insert comma first if variable is not valid

Tags: php, sql, email

i am running an SQL INSERT query inserting the following variables:

```
'".$emails_list."".$extra_emails_list."".$cc_email_to."',
```

i need to seperate each email address with  a *,* so the $cc_email_to var looks like:

```
$cc_email_to = ','.$_POST["email_cc"];
```

but if the `$emails_list` or `$extra_emails_list` having no email addresses in them the $cc_email_to variable is inserting `, email@domain.com` and when the email tries to send i get errors as there is a , first and not an email address

how can i make the *,* not insert if there is nothing before but insert the *,* if there is other data to add before?

Comment: It's not recommended to put several values in one fields

Answer (score 0):

Besides your code style and the potential security issue with user input directly in SQL statement,

you are looking for `implode();`.

Example:

```
$mails = array('test@test.com', 'bla@bla.com');

if (is_array($mails)) {
    echo implode(',', $mails); //prints test@test.com,bla@bla.com
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One easy solution would be to go the other way and create your variables like that

```
$cc_email_to .= $_POST["email_cc"].',';
if($emails_list!=null) $emails_list .=$_POST["email_list "].',';
if($extra_emails_list!=null) $extra_emails_list .= $_POST["extra_email_list "].',';
```

This way the final string will be safe.

However I would suggest not saving like that in the database. Create tables that hold personal information representing objects and use an ORM like Doctrine to achieve a more robust and extensible solution.